# client not connecting with server C (Socket programming)

Tags: c, sockets

I have a very simple client and server code:

client

```
int sockfd = 0;
    int bytesReceived = 0;
    char recvBuff[BUFSIZE];
    memset(recvBuff, '0', sizeof(recvBuff));
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    printf("here i am\n");
    /* Create a socket first */
    if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))< 0){
        printf("\n Error : Could not create socket \n");
        return 1;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "connection stats\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "connecting to %d - %s \n",port,server);
    /* Initialize sockaddr_in data structure */
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port); // port
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = server;
    printf(" attempting connection %s:%d\n", server, port);
    /* Attempt a connection */
     int con =  connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
     printf("Error %d\n", con);
    exit(-1);
```

And server

```
   int listenfd = 0;
    int connfd = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    char sendBuff[BUFSIZE];
    int numrv;

    listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    printf("Socket retrieve success\n");

    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
    memset(sendBuff, '0', sizeof(sendBuff));
    printf("here 2\n");
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    printf("here 3\n");
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    printf("here 4\n");
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    printf("here 5\n");
    int optval = 1;
    printf(" opening port %d\n", port);
    setsockopt(listenfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,
               (const void *) &optval, sizeof(int));
    bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    printf("binded\n");


    while (1) {
        connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) NULL, NULL);
        printf("connfd %d", connfd);


        close(connfd);
        sleep(1);


    }
```

Client output:

```
here i am
connecting to 8888 - localhost 
 attempting connection localhost:8888
```

Server output

```
Socket retrieve success
here 2
here 3
here 4
here 5
 opening port 8888
binded
```

And after like few minutes of wait.. I observe the following:
Client:

```
here i am
connecting to 8888 - localhost 
 attempting connection localhost:8888
Error -1
```

Server:

```
Socket retrieve success
here 2
here 3
here 4
here 5
 opening port 8888
binded
connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd -1connfd
```

which by -1, I can guess that the connection has failed.
I am not sure what I am missing?

Comment: You should put a `\n` after `connfd %d`, or else printf's output will be buffered and you won't see it right when it happens. You could also call `fflush` to print buffered output

Comment: @Eregrith: You are correct.. so basically, the connect fails instantaneously.. But I am not sure.. why server is not accepting client connection..

Comment: Have a look at `errno` and `perror` maybe that can help, cross it with [the connect() manual](http://linux.die.net/man/2/connect)

Comment: In theory connect should block, but this depends on your environment. Try not exiting from the client immediately, but send some data and wait some time (100ms) in a loop.

Comment: @vbence you can't send some data if connect returns `-1`.

Comment: So, I modified my serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = server; to serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(server);
And.. now the client fails immediately... but no changes in server.. server is still in while loop spitting -1 I am hoping the server to wait for connections (so the code is blocked on that line..and when client connects the server, continues)

Comment: Do note that memsetting something to `'0'` is very different from `0`, which probably was intended...

Comment: Ok.. So based on @alk comments below. I am able to make it work.. but basically instead I have to use serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); but is there a way that I can instead init it with "localhost"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server misses to call `listen()` on the bound socket prior to calling `accept()` on it.

---

Also this

```
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = server;
```

should have issued a warning by the compiler. You cannot assign a C-"string" (what I assume `server` is) to an `in_addr_t` (what `serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr` is).

Fix this by doing:

```
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(server);
```

or better add error checking to this, like so:

```
{
  in_addr_t in_addr = inet_addr(server);
  if (INADDR_NONE == in_addr)
  {
    perror("inet_addr() failed");
    abort(); /* or whatever error handling you choose. */
  }

  serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = in_addr;
}
```

Comment: Yepp.. that did solves.. so now the server is waiting for incoming connections.. but client is not able to connect to it.. am i missing anything on my client code?

Comment: Ok.. So I am able to make this work.. Instead of localhost, if I have serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); Then it works fine? But I actually have string localhost? Is there a way to initialize localhost..instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: I get PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.011 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.018 ms
 But when I use localhost instead of 127.0.0.1, the client connection fails (returns -1)

Comment: @Fraz: You need to go via `getaddrinfo()` to pull the ip-address for a symbolic name.